# Calling a class method present in another class from another class

Tags: java

Create  the below 3 class in a source file named as Sport:
a) Create two non-public class Hockey and class Football, with one method which will print the name of the game i.e getSportName().
b) Create one more class SportTest. Inside the main method of this class create the object of Hockey and Football and print the name of respective game with the help of method.

Comment: That's basic OOP. Thats described in every tutorial!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to do multiple inheritance, `extend` one class and `implement` another, that way methods can be accessed.

eg. Following is the pseudocode to do multiple inheritance:

```
class A{
    public:
    void method1();
}
interface B{
    public:
    abstract void method2();
}

class C extends A implements B{}

C c = new C();
c.method1();
c.method2();
```

Comment: @Morchul sorry, that was a typo

Comment: @Morchul, and FYI, beginners should google for tutorials, it is that simple, we here can give solutions, but it doesnt mean we are here to provide the code from scratch or tutor them. My work here is done as I was supposed to provide the basic idea, that I have provided, if the beginner is curious, he/she will do research on it.

Comment: I'm not sure a beginner understand the pseudocode but ok it's not so important. But I don't think your answer works for his issue because he has two classes which has methods to return their names. With your answer you can't get the names of class A and B in class C because in class B you don't have any methods who can return the name (except of static methods)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Sport class in SportTest constructor so you have access to the Sport class and the Football and Hockey class:

```
public class Sport(){
    public Football football;
    public Hockey hockey;
    public Sport(){
        football = new Football();
        hockey = new Hockey();
    }
}

public class Football{
    String getName(){return "Football";}
}
public class Hockey{
    String getName(){return "Hockey";}
}

public class SportTest{
    public SportTest(Sport sport){
        sport.football.getName(); // "Football"
        sport.hockey.getName;     // "Hockey"
    }
}
```

Or instead of holding Football and Hockey in Sport class. You can make Sport to a interface and implement Sport in the Football and Hockey classes:

```
public interface Sport(){
    String getName();
}

public class Football implements Sport{
    @Override
    String getName(){return "Football";}
}
public class Hockey implements Sport{
    @Override
    String getName(){return "Hockey";}
}

public class SportTest{
    public SportTest(Sport sport){
        sport.getName();
    }
}

SportTest footballTest = new SportTest(new Football()); // "Football"
SportTest hockeyTest = new HockeyTest(new Hockey()); // "Hockey"
```